# Why don't we use base64 instead of hex?

Tags: binary, numbers, hex, base64

If we use hex because it's a simplification of binary that makes things easier on the programmer, is easier to read than binary, and carries more data, (etc.,) why do we not jump to the next logical step, base64?

**Example:**

In decimal:
1,000,000<sub>10</sub>

In binary:
0b11110100001001000000<sub>2</sub>

In hex:
0xf4240<sub>16</sub>

---

Clearly, the base64 representation of the above will be even more compact and succinct than even the hex representation.

For that matter, why don't we use an arbitrarily large 2<sup>n</sup> base system? Why stop at hex, specifically?

Comment: Which one is easier for a human to convert? Hex or base64?

Comment: Can you really remember (or decipher) what the binary representation of `I34` is?  If you can't, then it's not actually that useful.  There are also the problems with the fact that each letter represents 6 bits instead of a multiple of the word sizes we use (4, 8 bits).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hex has a useful property of using two digits to a single byte. This is very convenient for looking at raw memory, memory addresses, etc. Back in my PDP days we used octal a lot, because we could read machine code easier. Base-64 does not offer such nice divisibility: it's 6 bits, so it is 4 digits for 3 bytes.

Comment: Correction: 4 symbols for 3 bytes.  Digits specifically refer to those symbols that work in a base-10 system.

Comment: @bdares [Your statement about decimal system is not entirely accurate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit). The word "digit" may be used to describe symbols in any positional numerical system.

Comment: By this logic, wouldn't one symbol per byte be even easier to read?

Comment: oi!  I refuse to acknowledge wikipedia's authority on this, as with using "they" to refer to single people.

Comment: @ChrisBlake Most definitely! There is one problem, though: people whose native tongue is not Chinese or Japanese would need to learn a great deal of new symbols to make up for the 220 missing "digits". Even with enough glyphs in your memory you'd need to remember the encoding table. In contrast, hex forces you to remember the meaning of only six additional "digits", which come in a familiar order, making it easy to memorize.

Comment: I'm sorry; but I'm not quite understanding what you mean by "missing digits".

Comment: @ChrisBlake Of the 256 digits that you need for base-256 system you automatically know the first ten (0..9). You also know 26 letters that you can use for your next 26 digits, for a total of 36 available "digit" symbols. You need additional `256-36=220` symbols to use for additional digits.

Answer (score 2):

Quick, what's the binary or decimal value of the symbol `K`?  (Or if I tell you to separate `K` objects out from a pile, can you do it without having to spend a few minutes figuring out what that value actually means?)

If you have to count while reciting the alphabet song, you will realize what the problem with using base-64 is as a written number system.  Heck, you have to use a song to remember what the order of 26 symbols is (at least I do), how can you remember 64 of them?

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is already used as an encoding system for a variety of tasks. In Java for example there are many implementations [like here](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) for example. It can be useful for transporting encoded data in xml.

Comment: I meant, why don't we use it specifically for numbers, in the place of hex.

Comment: Then you should say that in your question